# Package 'iconv' unavailable for R 4.1.3

Tags: r, utf-8, iconv

I want to convert latin-1 encoding to UTF-8 encoding in R 4.1.3 with the 'iconv' package, but seems it's not available for newer versions of R. Anyone knows which package I can use?

I'm running the R kernel in JupyterLab and got this warning message:

Warning message:
"package 'iconv' is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
[https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages%22)

Comment: `iconv` is a function in base R

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/iconv.html

Comment: You don't need to install anything to use `iconv`. It is a base R function. What code are you trying to run exactly and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using the R kernel in JupyterLab and got this message after running iconv:                                                                                                      
Warning message:
"package 'iconv' is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages"

Comment: @DiegoDávilaVilchez ; can you also show how you are calling `iconv` please

Comment: @user20650 the warning appears when I try to install the package "install.packages('iconv')"

Comment: okay. thanks. you do not need to install it. it comes with R and so you should just be able to use it.